Spring+OAuth2: authentication fails when multiple tabs are opened in quick succession
As the title says, I have a spring boot app and OAuth2 works as expected when user opens multiple tabs one after the other. However, when user clicks a link multiple times in quick succession (opening multiple tabs before one tab is loaded), the application is redirected to logout screen (and sometimes it is redirected to /login?error).
How do we ensure that all the tabs authenticated and ensure user is taken to the expected screen?
I'm using spring boot: 3.1.2.
The issue I'm experiencing is very similar to: the issue here.
Note: This is not an issue if the user opens a new tab, waits for the authentication flow to complete and open another tab.
Update:
After debugging, the error I am seeing is: authorization_request_not_found. It looks like request is lost before being authenticated. How do we prevent this?

I would note the behavior and move on.  Otherwise, you're going to spend a very long time solving a problem that is unlikely to ever manifest.
